# How to set the upper bound on a scrapy spider ReturnsContract

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to limit the number of items I find in each pages.

I found [this documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html) that seems to fit what I need:

```
class scrapy.contracts.default.ReturnsContract

This contract (@returns) sets lower and upper bounds for the items and 
requests returned by the spider. The upper bound is optional:

@returns item(s)|request(s) [min [max]]
```

But I don't understand how to use this class. In my spider, I tried to add

```
ReturnsContract.__setattr__("max",10)
```

But it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spider Contracts](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html) are meant for testing purposes, not to control your data extraction logic.

> Testing spiders can get particularly annoying and while nothing
>   prevents you from writing unit tests the task gets cumbersome quickly.
>   Scrapy offers an integrated way of testing your spiders by the means
>   of contracts.
>
> This allows you to test each callback of your spider by hardcoding a
>   sample url and check various constraints for how the callback
>   processes the response. Each contract is prefixed with an @ and
>   included in the docstring.

For your purpose, you can simply set an upper bound in your extraction logic, for example:

`response.xpath('//my/xpath').extract()[:10]`

Comment: I want to add an upper bound so my spider is "polite". I think this is scraping the full website but returning 10 results. It is still better than what I found, so I will probably use it.

Comment: If you want to limit the number of items or the number of pages to crawl, take a look at the close spider extension: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider. You can configure your spider to stop after it has scraped X items or requested X pages